# How can I set readonly attribute to FileContentResult

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am generating a new file in my controller and returning it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("configurationFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ConfigDto request)
{
    var jsonBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
    return new FileContentResult(jsonBytes, "application/json")
    {
        FileDownloadName = $"Configuration_{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.config"
    };
}
```

How can I set the attribute readonly to this file?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible as you basically just send him Bytes. The only time I saw that behavior is on SharePoint when you don't have write permissions on the file but I mean anyway you can still create a copy of the file to edit it so.
What is your exact purpose?

Comment: Basically it is a config file, which is used later to jump to a given state of my application. so would be nice if it cannot be edited. Yes, I know the user can override and still edit the file if he really wants. But just one of the nice to have features so that the file by default is not editable

Comment: I don't really think it is possible, but the only way I could think of is creating the file on your server, put it to readonly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=netframework-4.7.2), then create your FileContentResult from your file itself. 
But I don't know if the attributes will be kept. Just throwing an idea